# Inverse Power Strip

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image: Pirts Rewop]

You surely have [A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_strip) in your house. B looks if [xkcd](https://xkcd.com) might have
had the same nightmare as I had tonight (I didn't check).
Does this actually exist? I can't think of a *sensible*
application.

Comment: What does `B` do ?

Comment: B allows one to power a device and to electrocute one who touches the open end. This is called a suicide cord, when used without the intermediate outlet, often to connect generators to house curcuits.

Comment: To my horror I've seen something similar (not exactly the same) used as a makeshift.  It was a power strip without a plug in that was powered through the power strip sockets by a male male extension cable. Someone could unplug the powered cable and touch the live and ...well you know the rest. Another suitable name might be "russian roulette cable".

Comment: @NMech Yep, a tech working for me built a slick little field test box. Didn't want prongs sticking out of it, so he put a receptacle on it and built a male-male cord for it. We never let him live it down. Similarly, one of my coworkerd spent an entire day stringing Christmas lights starting at the far end and working towards the outlets. He had them the wrong way around, and came to me wanting me to make a male-male cord for them.

Comment: There was an example of this over on Home Improvement.SE a few days ago. It was hardwired in a subpanel.

Comment: Worst example I've seen was an add-on hot water heater. The person wasn't thinking very far ahead-it was 240 volts. They tried pulling one leg from the closet light with a bulb-to-plug adapter (the fixture was rated at 150W) and the other leg from a nearby outlet. It didn't end well.

Answer (score 0):

When plugged into interior wall sockets fed by the two different phases of a residential circuit panel, the two different hots could produce 240v AC.

Comment: I've seen this as well. A motel's wiring was modded for the rooms to have smoke detectors and fire alarms running off the same leg (the alarm panel required this). One out three rooms didn't have the correct phase. The solution to these rooms was to add a drop to one outlet, have it split-breakered (there is a specific exception in the code for fire system retrofits), and to break the tab off the duplex receptacle to isolate the two. Twenty years later, someone replaced an outlet and didn't break the tab off. Three vacuum cleaners later, someone finally called me.